# Where is the documentation for the return values of the IBM Weather Service?

Tags: weather-api

I do not find a full documentation of all return values of the Weather Service REST Api calls

The is only the JSON description like https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/rest-api/
But was does each value mean?

For example what is: 
"rh":  ?
"wspd": ?
"wdir": ?

There is a getting started https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Weather/index.html?pos=2 , but I do not find the full documentation.

Here is a example for the JSON ...

```
 "forecasts": [
    {
      "class": "string",
      "expire_time_gmt": 0,
      "fcst_valid": 0,
      "fcst_valid_local": "2016-09-05",
      "temp": 0,
      "icon_extd": 0,
      "icon_code": 0,
      "dow": "string",
      "phrase_12char": "string",
      "phrase_22char": "string",
      "phrase_32char": "string",
      "pop": 0,
      "precip_type": "string",
      "rh": 0,
      "wspd": 0,
      "wdir": 0,
      "wdir_cardinal": "string",
      "gust": 0,
      "mslp": 0,
      "num": 0,
      "day_ind": "string",
      "dewpt": 0,
      "hi": 0,
      "wc": 0,
      "feels_like": 0,
      "subphrase_pt1": "string",
      "subphrase_pt2": "string",
      "subphrase_pt3": "string",
      "qpf": 0,
      "snow_qpf": 0,
      "clds": 0,
      "uv_index_raw": 0,
      "uv_index": 0,
      "uv_desc": "string",
      "uv_warning": 0,
      "golf_index": 0,
      "golf_category": "string",
      "severity": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the documentation of the [Weather Company Data API](https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/rest-api-deprecated/#!/twc_forecast_daily/v2fcstdaily10) (still Bluemix but now deprecated) provides way more information.

For example, it says:

**rh**: (integer) The daytime relative humidity of the air, [...] is always expressed as a percentage.

**wspd**: (integer) The maximum forecasted daytime wind speed.

**wdir**: (integer) Daytime average wind direction in magnetic notation.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty complete documentation of all the return values can be found here: https://www.worldcommunitygrid.org/lt/images/climate/The_Weather_Company_APIs.pdf